# Is it possible to reduce the timeout (10s?) during cluster update by actively shutting down the leader?

Tags: aeron

If AeronCluster wants to update the leader node when running, the cluster will face the heartbeat timeout (10s?) unavailability. Is it possible to add a signal to ClusterTools to make the leader node abdicate and let other followers actively start the election? (I tried `remove-member`, but the node cannot join the cluster later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible by running the media driver separate from the consensus module on each node. To reduce the 10s timeout on the leader the consensus module on the leader can be closed while leaving the media driver on the leader running. The followers will then detect the log channel has closed and immediately enter a new election.

Comment: Have you tried anything like this with success? It seems to increase the complexity of operation and maintenance. I saw a similar function description in Diego Ongaro's [Ph.D. dissertation](https://github.com/ongardie/dissertation)(Chapter 3, Section 10). If I want to contribute to this part of the function, is there anything I need to pay attention to?

Comment: Yes this can work and there are things you need to pay attention too. This type of operation is complex, and the complexity is essential. Helping people with this is how some of us make a living selling support and consultancy.